# Convert list to list option

Tags: types, f#

It is pretty easy, my function returns a `Group list` but the value I try to assign the value to is of type `Group list option` how can I convert the `Group list` to `Group list option`.

Here is my code

```
let ParseGroupList jsonData =
    let parsed = GroupProvider.Parse(jsonData).JsonValue.AsArray()
                |> List.ofArray
    let groups = List.map (fun grp -> ParseGroup(grp.ToString())) parsed
    groups

let ParseUser jsonData = 
    let parsed = UserProvider.Parse jsonData
    let mutable user = new User()
    user.ID <- parsed.Id
    user.Firstname <- parsed.Firstname
    user.Lastname <- parsed.Lastame
    user.Emailaddress <- parsed.Emailaddress
    user.Active <- parsed.Active
    user.AllGroupsCount <- parsed.Groupcount
    match parsed.Groups with
    | Some groups -> user.Groups <- ParseGroupList groups <= This doesn't work
    | None -> user.Groups <- None
    user

and public  User() =
    let mutable id = 0
    let mutable firstname = ""
    let mutable lastname = ""
    let mutable emailaddress = ""
    let mutable active = false

    let mutable groupscount = Option<int>.None
    let mutable groups = Option<Group list>.None

    member this.ID with get() = id and set(value) = id <- value
    member this.Firstname with get() = firstname and set(value) = firstname <- value
    member this.Lastname with get() = lastname and set(value) = lastname <- value
    member this.Emailaddress with get() = emailaddress and set(value) = emailaddress <- value
    member this.Active with get() = active and set(value) = active <- value

    member this.AllGroupsCount with get() = groupscount and set(value) = groupscount <- value
    member this.Groups with get() = groups and set(value) = groups <- value
```

The reason, why I use the option type, is that the JSON basically parses with a few optional attributes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Some(x)
```

will do the trick and covert `x` to an option type

Comment: Where exactly? I need the list as list option in this part: `Some groups -> user.Groups <- ParseGroupList groups`

Comment: `user.Groups <- Some (ParseGroupList groups)`

Comment: Thanks, helped me a lot, but I have many more problems, hopefully they'll be solved here the same good :)